# Retrieving data from SQLServer mutitenant database

Tags: sql-server, multi-tenant

I have a multitenant database with something like the following naming structure:

Sch1.Logins   => 2 records 
Sch2.Logins   => 4 Records

Now I want to be able to "Execute as" different users , say when user1 tries to run the query "select * from Logins", the results should be returned from the Sch1.Logins (2 records) and when user2 runs the same query, it would return records from Sch2.Logins.

1. How can I do this?
2. What settings are required for each user?

Answer (score 2):

Set the default schema for the users. You can see this in the user properties window through SQL Server Management Studio.

Or script:

```
ALTER USER user1 
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Sch1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But unless we set the owned schema for the user, it doesnt seem to work. Why would that be?

Comment: Shouldn't need to set the owner. They just need permission to read the tables in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

The following method seemed to work for me. Created a new user and associated it with a login. Then kept associating the relevant user different schemas.

```
 Use *MyDatabase*

Create User test2
For 
Login *myLogin* 
With Default_Schema = S1001 -- This is to map the created user to login

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::S1001 TO test2;

EXECUTE AS USER = 'test2'
select count(*) from Login

REVERT

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::S1001 TO dbo;

ALTER USER test2 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = S1002
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::S1002 TO test2;

EXECUTE AS USER = 'test2'
select count(*) from Login

Revert
```